# How to distribute FindXXX.cmake

Tags: cmake

I have a CMake project that generates a library. I have written a CMake script, FindXXX.cmake, to help users of my library. This way they can use find_package(XXX) and get the variables needed. So far so good.

The problem now is that users have copied this FindXXX.cmake into their own projects. If I modify it, they will just stick with the former one.

Is there a common way to distribute such a script? Should my installer put it in some special location so that CMake finds it without having users copying it in their project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to copy to [`${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#variable:CMAKE_ROOT). You may need system administrator rights.

Another solution could be add some registry entry on Windows: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Kitware\CMakeSetup\Settings\StartPath`. You should add the next `WhereBuild{i}` value to your project CMake files. The trick here is that the CMake search for known libraries from the previously-used libraries.

Based on the [suggested documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:find_package):

You should create the following library and copy FindProjectName.cmake:
*C:\Program Files\ProjectName\CMake* on Windows, */usr/local/ProjectName/share/cmake* on Linux.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Copying to ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules should make the trick.

Comment: Copying to ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules is discouraged. If CMake is uninstalled and then re-installed, your file will not be there anymore. See my other answer to this question for an alternate technique.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, while copying a FindXXX.cmake file to ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules will work, there are several other locations your project can put a "project configuration file" instead where CMake will find it automatically *without* a FindXXX.cmake file.

According to the *[find_package documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure)* you can install your project configuration file into your own installation tree, and CMake will find it, if your installation tree is in one of the "conventional" locations.

Look for the text on that page that begins with "CMake constructs a set of possible installation prefixes for the package" to see the details about where you can install your project configuration file so that CMake finds it automatically.

Comment: CMake only searches your own installation tree (`<prefix>/share/<projectname>` when searching for packages in "config" mode. When in this mode, it doesn't look for `FindProjectName.cmake` but for `ProjectNameConfig.cmake`. Bit annoying because it took me a while to figure out why my files weren't found :-)

Comment: Right. I updated my answer to be more clear. I had intended to be speaking of "project config files" all along, and had inadvertently kept talking about "FindXXX.cmake" modules as if they were equivalent. They are not: they are two separate mechanisms for obtaining the same information. One with a "search here" technique to locate the project in the first place (the Find modules), and one with a "found a project config file in an expected location, just load it" technique (the project config files)... Thanks for your comment, it prompted me to correct a long-standing mistake.